# SQL return value priorities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a SQL Server query where it will look through a table with millions of rows for a certain set of values, if it doesn't exist then return the most recent value.

Let's say we have this table:

```
id | phone_number  | status   | create_date  
---|-------------- | -------- | ---------------  
1  | 123-123-1234  | ANSWER   | xxx  
2  | 123-123-1234  | MACHINE  | xxx  
3  | 123-123-1234  | HANGUP   | xxx  
4  | 123-123-1234  | CALLBACK | xxx
```

Each transaction is a row.

I need to look up all the numbers from certain date range, if a phone_number had certain status in a set of values return that id, if not return the most recent id. But just a single record per phone_number

I know the syntax is wrong but I guess will explain my idea a little bit better.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions t
WHERE create_date = '2013-10-10' AND
(id = (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM transactions
  WHERE t.phone_number = phone_number AND status IN ('ANSWER','CALLBACK')
) OR (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM transactions
  WHERE t.phone_number = phone_number
)
```

If an ANSWER status exists within the time range return the most recent ID with that status from that number, if not then a CALLBACK if not any other status. And this for all phone_numbers.

I would expect something like this as a result:

```
id | phone_number | status   | create_date  
-- | ------------ | -------- | ----------  
1  | 123-123-1234 | ANSWER   | xxx  
20 | 321-321-3210 | HANGUP   | xxx  
30 | 123-312-2310 | CALLBACK | xxx
```

...

Thanks!

Comment: your overall where clause boils down to `where (id = XXX) or (true)` and essentially returns everything. `id = (...) or (...)` is not going to be doing what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you were trying to do:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT id, phone_number, status, create_date,
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (
    PARTITION BY phone_number 
    ORDER BY CASE [status]
      WHEN 'ANSWER' THEN 1
      WHEN 'CALLBACK' THEN 2 ELSE 3
    END, create_date)
  FROM dbo.yourtable
)
SELECT id, phone_number, status, create_date FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98885/3)

Comment: Plain and simple - had 0 knowledge of OVER PARTITION BY. Thanks!